# Remove items (both keys and values) from a dictionary if they are present in another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have two Python dictionaries:

```
A = {1: 27, 3: 41, 7: 26, 11: 32, 12: 23, 14: 23, 15: 37, 18: 27, 21: 35, 23: 12, 25: 33, 26: 7, 27: 1, 29: 14, 32: 11, 33: 25, 35: 21, 36: 27, 37: 15, 38: 25, 39: 23, 41: 3, 44: 27}
```

and

```
B = {1: 27, 3: 41, 7: 26, 11: 32, 12: 23, 15: 37, 18: 27, 21: 35, 26: 7, 29: 14, 32: 11, 33: 25, 35: 21, 36: 27, 39: 23, 41: 3, 44: 27}
```

I want to remove all numerical values that are present in dictionary B from dictionary A. By this, I mean if a number is present in dictionary B as a key or a value, then it must be totally removed from dictionary A from its keys or values (also even if the number is present in one of the values multiple times).

So my desired output should be

```
38
```

as rest of all the numbers are present in dictionary B and dictionary A, but 38 is unique one in B (by eyeballing).

So far, I have tried the following:

```
C = {k: v for k, v in A.items() if k not in B}
```

This gives me:

```
C = {14: 23, 23: 12, 25: 33, 27: 1, 37: 15, 38: 25}
```

Clearly, this is not what I want.
I also tried:

```
C = dict(A.items() - B.items())
```

Didn't work either.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Why should `{38: 25}` from `A` remain? 38 does not appear as a key or a value in `B`, *but* it's value 25 does appear in `B` in entry `{33: 25}`. According to your spec... "must be totally removed from dictionary A from its keys or values". Here 25 _does_ appear as a value in `A` and should therefore be removed. You should end up with an empty dict.

Comment: Or should the resultant dict be `{38: None}`?

Comment: You are right. I was looking for something like {38: none}. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that creates a results dictionary consisting of items from `A` that have either no key or no value in `B`. In the case that only one of the key or value is in `B`, that key or value is replaced with `None`. Note that this is problematic if there is more than one key value pair for which the key is in `B` but the value is not (multiple `None` keys).

```
from itertools import chain

A = {1: 27, 3: 41, 7: 26, 11: 32, 12: 23, 14: 23, 15: 37, 18: 27, 21: 35, 23: 12, 25: 33, 26: 7, 27: 1, 29: 14, 32: 11, 33: 25, 35: 21, 36: 27, 37: 15, 38: 25, 39: 23, 41: 3, 44: 27, 100: 200, 300: 1000, 400: 2000}
B = {1: 27, 3: 41, 7: 26, 11: 32, 12: 23, 15: 37, 18: 27, 21: 35, 26: 7, 29: 14, 32: 11, 33: 25, 35: 21, 36: 27, 39: 23, 41: 3, 44: 27, 300: 400}

b = set(chain(B.keys(), B.values()))
result = {}

for k,v in A.items():
    if k not in b or v not in b:
        new_key = k if k not in b else None
        new_val = v if v not in b else None
        result[new_key] = new_val

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{38: None, 100: 200, None: 2000}
```

This can be summarised into this dictionary comprehension which produces the same output:

```
{k if k not in b else None: v if v not in b else None
    for k, v in A.items() if k not in b or v not in b}
```

But notice that `{None: 1000}` should also be present because although the key 300 is in B, its value 1000 is not. Collecting the results in a dictionary loses those items with `None` as a duplicate key except for the last one processed.

So, instead of collecting the results in a dict, use a list of tuples:

```
[(k if k not in b else None, v if v not in b else None)
        for k, v in A.items() if k not in b or v not in b]
```

Output:

```
[(38, None), (100, 200), (None, 1000), (None, 2000)]
```

Another option (not shown here) is to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists which will allow you to create a dictionary that will keep a list of values that share the duplicate `None` key.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sets.  Sets do not have duplicates.  You can find the union, intersection, and difference of two sets.  The code below turns the keys and values of each dictionary into sets and creates a union of keys and values.  Then it finds the difference between two sets.

```
a_set = set(A.keys()).union(set(A.values()))
b_set = set(B.keys()).union(set(B.values()))
print(a_set.difference(b_set))

#output:{38}
```

Comment: @SayantaSeth  You are welcome.  Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it works better for you.